# Construct a DFA for the following language: L={a^n b^n | n>=1}

Tags: computation-theory

in the language, n is power but I didn't know how to write.

Comment: Did you forget a homework tag by any chance?

Answer (score 11):

I think you misunderstood your homework (not to mention the classes themselves). That language **isn't regular**. What that means is, you can't construct a DFA for it.

Think about it: as you're going through the loop over `a`, you're not holding anywhere the number of times you executed the state. You have no way of knowing how many times to read `b`.

This can be done with a context free grammar like this however:

```
S->aSb|ab
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you go over the Regular Pumping lemma in your class?

There's a similar pumping lemma for Context Free languages as well

Comment: Example for this specific language: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Use_of_lemma